# PHP Random Number Generator, want 0 most of the time

Tags: php

How can I make this PHP Random Number Generator to output "0" most of the time.
consider this is the Google Pay cashback code, most of the time we get nothing as cashback, just like that.
50-70% of the time, the code should output only "0".
The higher numbers should show up only few times.

```
<?php
srand(time());
mt_srand(time());
echo mt_rand(0,20) . "<br>";
?>
```

another idea is to use a code like following, is there a better option ?

```
<?php
function randomName() {
    $names = array(
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        '10',
        '11',
        '12',
        '13',
        '14',
        '15',
        '16',
        '17',
        '18',
        '19',
        '20',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        '0',
        // and so on

    );
    return $names[rand ( 0 , count($names) -1)];
}

print randomName();
?>
```

Comment: Why not check for that 70% rate before computing a random number?

Comment: @vivek_23, we are not giving cashback for confirmed orders, we are giving cashback almost every clicks.

Comment: @Mithun Ok, as your business policy goes.

Comment: ok, someone deleted my initial comment. The "why" needs to be made clear to me for me to better understand what to say and what not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to increase the range of your call to `mt_rand` and make the upper part of it map to a `0` value. For example:

```
mt_srand(time());
$pct_zero = 70;
$raw =  mt_rand(0,floor(20*100/(100-$pct_zero)));
$raw = $raw > 20 ? 0 : $raw;
echo $raw;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Nicks answer, but more hardcoded.  Expand the range of the random number( in this I use 0-50),but subtract 30 to mean the range is actually 20 to -30 and then use `max()` with 0 to make all negative numbers 0...

```
echo max(0, mt_rand(0, 50)-30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just fill the array which covers up 50-70% of the array with `0`. Then you can just generate an array index randomly and you should get a `0` 50-70% of the times.

```
<?php

$arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,15,20,25];
shuffle($arr);

for($i=1;$i<=10;++$i){
  echo $arr[rand(0,count($arr)-1)],"\n";
}
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2bfb5a97e161d4c3e18cc264459e88f3c17fec0